# Area of a Rectangle

Tags: assembly, lc3

I need to ask the user to input to values and find out the area of the rectangle and output. I have the program where it will ask the user for the to inputs but when it goes to output it outputs the completely wrong answer

The program is written in assembly for LC-3. I have tried multiple different techniques of trying to output the value but all come with similar results. It will either output a number no where near right or a random symbol.

```
.ORIG x3000

; Reset Registers
AND R0, R0, #0
AND R1, R1, #0
AND R2, R2, #0
AND R3, R3, #0
AND R4, R4, #0
AND R5, R5, #0
AND R6, R6, #0
AND R7, R7, #0

LEA R0, numberone
PUTS
GETC
OUT
LD R3, HEXN30 
ADD R0, R0, R3
ADD R1, R0, #0


LEA R0, numbertwo
PUTS
GETC
OUT
ADD R0, R0, R3
ADD R6, R0, #0
LOOP
      ADD R2, R2, R1
      ADD R6, R6, #-1
BRp LOOP

LEA R0, MESG 
PUTS
ADD R0, R2, x0

LD R2, NEG_TEN  
ADD R2, R2, R0  
BRn JUMP    
AND R4, R4, #0  
ADD R4, R4, R2  
LD R0, ASCII_1 
OUT    
AND R0, R0, #0  
ADD R0, R0, R4  

JUMP

LD R3, HEX30 ;add 30 to integer to get integer character
ADD R0, R0, R3
OUT 

HALT ;{TRAP 25}


numberone  .stringz "\nPlease enter the length: "
numbertwo  .stringz "\nPlease enter the width: "
MESG .STRINGZ  "\n\nThe Area of the Rectangle is: "
HEXN30 .FILL xFFD0 ; -30 HEX
HEX30 .FILL x0030 ; 30 HEX
NEG_TEN .FILL #-10
ASCII_1 .FILL x0031 ; ASCII char '1'
.END
```

```
The console should output the follow:

Please enter a length: 4 
Please enter a width: 5
The Area of the rectangle is: 20
```

Comment: Use a debugger to look at registers while your program runs.  Does LC3 not support `'0'` (`0x30`) as an immediate constant?  I'm surprised you have to load it from memory.

Comment: But anyway, `20` as an ASCII string takes 2 characters.  `20 + '0'` is some non-digit ASCII character.  Does your program work for small inputs like `3 * 3 = 9`  where the correct output is a single-digit number?  If so, then you need to implement output for multi-digit numbers.  (repeated division by 10.)  And BTW, specific examples of the actual output would be a better [mcve].

Comment: The LC3 has no 'load immediate' instruction. Best you can do is AND a register with an immediate 0, then add to it until you get the value you want. Or, load a memory address, like OP is doing.